# Tikz picture in Table, column adjustment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

One of the column in my table is tikzpicture and the rest are normal data. The data in the rest of the columns are displaced in the bottom but I want it to be displayed in the middle. Any help will be much appreciated. The code is given as follows.

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ booktabs }
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{longtable}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC,fit}
\newcommand\addvmargin[1]{
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner ysep=#1,inner xsep=0]{};
}



\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
 \label{tab!resultsraw}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ID}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{ weights Cube}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{T/J }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{data 1 }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{data 2} \\\hline

\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\vspace{-0.25em}\scriptsize\emph{\tablename\ \thetable{} continued from previous page}}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\scriptsize\emph{Continued on next page}}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
24097  & 
$\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line join=round,
  y={(-0.86cm,0.36cm)},x={(.6cm,0.36cm)}, z={(0cm,.8cm)},
  arr/.style={line cap=round,shorten <= 1pt}
]
\def\Side{1}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);\coordinate (A2) at (0,\Side,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (\Side,\Side,0);\coordinate (A4) at (\Side,0,0);\coordinate (B1) at (0,0,\Side);\coordinate (B2) at (0,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B3) at (\Side,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B4) at (\Side,0,\Side);

\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A1) -- (A4);\draw[thin] (B2) -- (B1) -- (B4) -- (B3) -- cycle;\draw[thin] (A1) -- (B1);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (B2);
\draw[thin] (A4) -- (B4);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A3);
\draw[thin] (A3) -- (B3);\draw[thin] (A3) -- (A4);



\path[arr] 
  (A1) edge (A2)
  (B2) edge (A2)
  (B1) edge (B2)
  (B1) edge (A1)
  (B4) edge (A4)
  (B3) edge (A3)
  (B4) edge (B3)
  (A4) edge (A3);

\node[below] at (A1) {$1$};
\node[below] at (A2) {$1$};
\node[below] at (A3) {$1$};
\node[below] at (A4) {$1$};
\node[above] at (B1) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B2) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B3) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B4) {$2$};

\end{tikzpicture}$ & TJJ    & $1:12 $    & $[9]$ \\\hline


12960  & 
$\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line join=round,
  y={(-0.86cm,0.36cm)},x={(.6cm,0.36cm)}, z={(0cm,.8cm)},
  arr/.style={line cap=round,shorten <= 1pt}
]
\def\Side{1}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);\coordinate (A2) at (0,\Side,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (\Side,\Side,0);\coordinate (A4) at (\Side,0,0);\coordinate (B1) at (0,0,\Side);\coordinate (B2) at (0,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B3) at (\Side,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B4) at (\Side,0,\Side);

\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A1) -- (A4);\draw[thin] (B2) -- (B1) -- (B4) -- (B3) -- cycle;\draw[thin] (A1) -- (B1);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (B2);
\draw[thin] (A4) -- (B4);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A3);
\draw[thin] (A3) -- (B3);\draw[thin] (A3) -- (A4);



\path[arr] 
  (A1) edge (A2)
  (B2) edge (A2)
  (B1) edge (B2)
  (B1) edge (A1)
  (B4) edge (A4)
  (B3) edge (A3)
  (B4) edge (B3)
  (A4) edge (A3);

\node[below] at (A1) {$2$};
\node[below] at (A2) {$2$};
\node[below] at (A3) {$2$};
\node[below] at (A4) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B1) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B2) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B3) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B4) {$2$};

\end{tikzpicture}$ & TJ & $2:12$ &$[6]$ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the height of the baseline using the `baseline={<coordinate>}` option for the `tikzpicture` environment. I used the center of the current bounding box to make it applicable to any `tikz` drawing, and y-shifted it slightly to be (fontsize dependent) vertically aligned with the other cells.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ booktabs }
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{longtable}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC,fit}
\newcommand\addvmargin[1]{
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner ysep=#1,inner xsep=0]{};
}



\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
 \label{tab!resultsraw}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ID}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{ weights Cube}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{T/J }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{data 1 }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{data 2} \\\hline

\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\vspace{-0.25em}\scriptsize\emph{\tablename\ \thetable{} continued from previous page}}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\scriptsize\emph{Continued on next page}}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
24097  & 
$\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line join=round,
  y={(-0.86cm,0.36cm)},x={(.6cm,0.36cm)}, z={(0cm,.8cm)},
  arr/.style={line cap=round,shorten <= 1pt},
  baseline={([yshift=-.5em]current bounding box.center)},
]
\def\Side{1}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);\coordinate (A2) at (0,\Side,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (\Side,\Side,0);\coordinate (A4) at (\Side,0,0);\coordinate (B1) at (0,0,\Side);\coordinate (B2) at (0,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B3) at (\Side,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B4) at (\Side,0,\Side);

\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A1) -- (A4);\draw[thin] (B2) -- (B1) -- (B4) -- (B3) -- cycle;\draw[thin] (A1) -- (B1);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (B2);
\draw[thin] (A4) -- (B4);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A3);
\draw[thin] (A3) -- (B3);\draw[thin] (A3) -- (A4);



\path[arr] 
  (A1) edge (A2)
  (B2) edge (A2)
  (B1) edge (B2)
  (B1) edge (A1)
  (B4) edge (A4)
  (B3) edge (A3)
  (B4) edge (B3)
  (A4) edge (A3);

\node[below] at (A1) {$1$};
\node[below] at (A2) {$1$};
\node[below] at (A3) {$1$};
\node[below] at (A4) {$1$};
\node[above] at (B1) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B2) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B3) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B4) {$2$};

\end{tikzpicture}$ & TJJ    & $1:12 $    & $[9]$ \\\hline


12960  & 
$\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line join=round,
  y={(-0.86cm,0.36cm)},x={(.6cm,0.36cm)}, z={(0cm,.8cm)},
  arr/.style={line cap=round,shorten <= 1pt},
  baseline={([yshift=-.5em]current bounding box.center)},
]
\def\Side{1}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);\coordinate (A2) at (0,\Side,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (\Side,\Side,0);\coordinate (A4) at (\Side,0,0);\coordinate (B1) at (0,0,\Side);\coordinate (B2) at (0,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B3) at (\Side,\Side,\Side);\coordinate (B4) at (\Side,0,\Side);

\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A1) -- (A4);\draw[thin] (B2) -- (B1) -- (B4) -- (B3) -- cycle;\draw[thin] (A1) -- (B1);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (B2);
\draw[thin] (A4) -- (B4);\draw[thin] (A2) -- (A3);
\draw[thin] (A3) -- (B3);\draw[thin] (A3) -- (A4);



\path[arr] 
  (A1) edge (A2)
  (B2) edge (A2)
  (B1) edge (B2)
  (B1) edge (A1)
  (B4) edge (A4)
  (B3) edge (A3)
  (B4) edge (B3)
  (A4) edge (A3);

\node[below] at (A1) {$2$};
\node[below] at (A2) {$2$};
\node[below] at (A3) {$2$};
\node[below] at (A4) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B1) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B2) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B3) {$2$};
\node[above] at (B4) {$2$};

\end{tikzpicture}$ & TJ & $2:12$ &$[6]$ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]